# Copy file in a bucket to a paperclip attachment with aws-sdk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I have a file in aws S3 that I want to copy to an active record paperclip attachment (as a copy of the file in a different bucket).

I have a reference to the object on S3 using the [aws-sdk](http://rubydoc.info/github/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/master/frames) gem:

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new(Rails.application.config.s3_creds)
obj = s3.buckets(uploads_bucket).objects.first
```

Say my active record model `my_model` has

```
has_attached_file :some_file
```

How do I copy `obj` into `my_model.some_file` ?

---

`my_model.some_file = obj` throws:
 **No handler found** for AWS::S3::S3Object:bucket/the_file.xls

`obj.copy_to(my_model.some_file)` throws **undefined method `scan'** for /file_name/original/missing.png:Paperclip::Attachment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm copying the file using AWS::S3::S3Object#copy_to(target_obj) and I get target obj by calling #s3_object() on the attachment after setting some column values and saving it:

```
my_model.some_file_file_name = obj.key
my_model.some_file_file_size = obj.content_length
my_model.some_file_content_type = obj.content_type
my_model.some_file_updated_at = obj.last_modified
my_model.save

obj.copy_to(my_model.some_file.s3_object)
```